# How do you say carry on in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to say 'carry on' in python?
eg -

```py
if i > 1:
         print('i is greater than 1')
     else:
         (carry on)
```

Is there a way to say the carry on in python?

Comment: Have you tried `pass`?

Comment: Is that just pass or like pass()

Answer (score 0):

```
if i>1:
    print("i is greater than 1")
else:
    pass
```

You can also keep an `if` without an `else`, but this answer is mostly for cases when "some-code" is required for indentation purposes, but should do nothing (more like empty brackets in Java or cpp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if i > 1:
    print('i is greater than 1')
else: 
    pass
```

But to be honest, from your question I don't understand why would you need an else statement if you don't want to do anything. You could just do:

```
if i > 1:
    print('i is greater than 1')
```

Comment: I was just giving a generic example off the top of my head. It is for something else but that was just the first if else statement I thought off.